# Deserialize items in JSON array to different enum values with associated values

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I am trying to deserialize a json like so

```json
{
    "timestamp": 123456789,
    "ownerAssets" : [
        {
            "ownerId" : 123,
            "location" : "USA",
            "assets" : [
                {
                    "car" : true,
                    "make" : "honda",
                    "model" : "crv"
                },
                {
                    "fruit" : true,
                    "name" : "apple",
                    "sweetness" : "high"
                    "count": 5
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ownerId" : 456,
            "location" : "USA",
            "assets" : [
                {
                    "car" : true,
                    "make" : "toyota",
                    "model" : "highlander"
                },
                {
                    "fruit" : true,
                    "name" : "orange",
                    "sweetness" : "low",
                    "count": 5
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I design the DTO models to parse this? I want to avoid using protocols and prefer to use enums with associated values.

I think the following is obvious:

```swift
struct StuffDTO: Codable {
    let timestamp: Int
    let ownerAssets: [OwnerAsset]
}

extension StuffDTO {
    struct OwnerAsset: Codable {
        let ownerId: Int
        let location: String
        let assets: [Asset]
    }
}
```

I could define an uber object which can parse everything and if-then-else this into different enums values(see below) with associated values of different types

```swift
struct Asset: Codable {
    // car fields
    let car: Bool?
    let make: String?
    let model: String?
    
    // fruit fields
    let fruit: Bool?
    let name: String?
    let sweetness: String?
    let count: Int?
}
```

But im wondering if there is a clever way to parse json directly into enum values, without parsing into an uber object or without using polymorphism/protocol.

```swift
enum Asset: Codable {
    case car(CarDTO)
    case fruit(FruitDTO)

    init() {
        // what would this custom json parsing logic look like?
    }
}

struct CarDTO: Codable {
    let make: String
    let model: String
}

struct FruitDTO: Codable {
    let name: String
    let sweetness: String
    let count: Int
}
```

Comment: Why not usimg dynamic.

Comment: write custom `Asset.init(from decoder: Decoder)` to detect and map associated types.

Answer (score 0):

You should first define a middle model like this:

```
struct BaseAsset: Codable {
    let type: AssetType
    let fruit: Bool
    let car: Bool

    enum AssetType {
        case car
        case fruit
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fruit
        case car
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        car = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .car) ?? false
        fruit = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .fruit) ?? false
        type = car ? .car : .fruit
    }
}
```

Then write Asset decoder like this:

```
enum Asset: Codable {
    case car(CarDTO)
    case fruit(FruitDTO)
    case unknown

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let type = try container.decode(BaseAsset.self).type
        switch type {
        case .car:
            self = .car(try container.decode(CarDTO.self))
        case .fruit:
            self = .fruit(try container.decode(FruitDTO.self))
        }
    }
}
```